# Timeout срабатывает после остановки QTimer

Tags: c++, qt

В основном классе `MainWidnow` определён `Qtimer* timer`. Внутри одного из методов класса timeout связывается с публичным слотом:

```
if (!timer)
{
    timer = new QTimer(this);
}
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(redraw()));
timer->start(2000);
```

Где `redraw()`:

```
void MainWindow::redraw()
{   
    QMessageBox msg;
    msg.setText("Called");
    msg.exec();
    if( !stack.isEmpty() )
    {
        stack[0]->mark ^=  stack[0]->mark || 1;
        stack[0]->edge->update();
        stack.removeFirst();
    }
    else
    {
        timer->stop();
        delete timer;
    }
}
```

Где `stack` - это QList. Если проверить дебаггером, то в условие остановки таймера и его удаления, функция входит вовремя, но при этом единожды срабатывает после остановки. В чём может быть причина? Если после этого снова запустить таймер, то функция вызывается дважды с интервалом меньше секунды, и после остановки вызывается дважды.

---

P.S.: что слот, что таймер вызываются лишь в одном методе на весь проект, а слот исключительно по таймауту.

Comment: А если `QMessageBox` заменить отладочной печатью? ЗЫ: не связано, но 1) если используешь QList как стек, то элементы следует брать/класть с хвоста а не с головы; 2) странный XOR...

Comment: @Fat-Zer результат тот же: на 1 вывод больше. Изначально проверки для XOR и removefirst не было - по окончании алгоритма регулярно получал ошибку о выходе за границы, только потом понял. Про XOR правда, написал первое что в голову пришло, можно заменить на ^= 1. Про QList тоже правда, спасибо, изменю

Comment: УМВР: https://paste.pound-python.org/show/ILwHoQpG6vYOLAcKYVEZ/

Comment: @Fat-Zer значит проблема локальная, возможно что-то с установкой связей не так

Comment: вряд ли... проверь что мой пример корректно работает, а потом можешь начать локализовывать проблему у себя... обрезай всё пока не останется только отладочная печать и установка таймера... [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Удаление объектов Qt следует выполнять при помощи `deleteLater`
2. Нет гарантии, что при удалении таймера в очереди событий не останутся события, которые радостно прибегут на следующем раунде обработки.

*Решение* - вызвать `disconnect`, когда в таймере отпадет необходимость.

Comment: Первый совет весьма спорный. Да, иногда приходится вызывать `deleteLater`, но это в целом порочная практика. C++ это про детерминированное освобождение ресурсов всё таки.

Comment: Я правильно понял силлогизм - вам не нравится, что удаление произойдет не прямо сейчас, а на следующем раунде очереди сообщений? Умными указателями вы также брезгуете?

Comment: Также я считаю порочной практикой использование термина "порочная практика" без указания конкретных проблем, к которым приводит ее применение.

Comment: Мне не нравится, что удаление произойдёт в неизвестный момент времени, после наступления неизвестного количества событий. Причём тут умные указатели мне не ясно, они как раз детерминированы. Конкретные проблемы вытекают из вышеозначенной недетерминированности. `deleteLater()` является костылём, созданным в силу наличия в самом Qt спорных мест, вот и всё. Подобный подход является нормальным для языков типа C#/Java и является чужеродным в C++.

Comment: Умные указатели я привел как пример потому, что момент удаления объекта в случае их использования определяется в рантайме - объект также будет удален неизвестно когда и неизвестно откуда. Особенно, если кодовая база большая и шареный ptr отправляется гулять в код другой команды.

Еще один момент - если приложение в какой-то момент захотят сделать многопоточным и разнести объекты по разным тредам, прямые вызовы delete превратятся в глюкодром.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888189/how-delete-and-deletelater-works-with-regards-to-signals-and-slots-in-qt/4889395#

Comment: Я согласен с тем, передача управления ресурсами какой-то там автоматике снижает контроль над кодом, что может повлиять на производительность. Но в HPC коде я, например, и исключения отрубаю и RTTI, и даже объекты не создаю и не удаляю. Для кода общего назначения, а тем более, для GUI - отказ от автоматического управления объектами есть преждевременная оптимизация. Проблема языков с жирным рантаймом типа C#  в том, что в них отрубить автоматику практически очень сложно, в отличии от C++, где программисту просто достаточно сменить стиль.

Comment: При нормальном написании кода, момент удаления умного указателя кристально ясен. То, что люди используют их там где не надо и от этого страдают — исключительно их проблемы. `shared_ptr` используется редко (среди хороших программистов), т.к. его функционал как правило избыточен. Что касается ответа по ссылке: он сильно отличается от Вашего утверждения, что удалять объекты Qt нужно с помощью `deleteLater`. Для такого удаления есть случаи, несомненно, но по умолчанию так делать не следует. Т.е. совет неплох с уточнением, но в таком виде он слишком спорный.

Comment: "Нормальное написание кода" - это обычно вторая-третья итерация рефакторинга. А вот чтобы до нее продукт дожил, следует писать максимально дубово.